# What would cause Windows to create temporary paging file?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, pagefile

After recent scheduled reboot when I remote to a server I get the following error message.

> Windows created a temporary paging file on your computer because of a
>   problem that occurred with your paging file configuration when you
>   started your computer. The total paging file size for all disk drives
>   may be somewhat larger than the size you specified.

When I click OK it goes to Performance Options to change Page File size. On that first screen it shows 656 MB. But on the second screen it shows it to be set on "Auto." This what makes me confused that it would be saying that size is set low but it showing to be set to "Auto"

I'm not sure how much free space was on the drive but now there is only 10GB of free space left. Therefore I have requested system team to increase the size of the drive and during next scheduled restart to set the page file to fixed size.

Anyone know if Windows might be unstable when running on Temporary Page File and should I wait until scheduled restart (in two weeks) or adjust this as soon as possible?

Answer (score 1):

It could lead to instability because your if your server uses all of the RAM and all of the space in the page file, applications will probably crash.  A 656 MB page file is extremely low.  Depending of the availability needs of your servers & the % of RAM used you might want to schedule an early reboot.  Unless you have a driving need, it is best to just let windows handle the page file size for all drives.